# IS It Possible to Manage (Full Screen) Video Screen in Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I successfully playing some channel in Roku. and I tried to all channel full screen in Roku I set height width of video player. But Now still not working. Anyone know these issue How to set The Video playing a Full Screen. Anyone know this issue. I'm working all three resolution 480P, 720P and 1080P.

**EDITED:**
[image]

**My monitor Status:**

[image]

**My Set-top Box Resolution:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set the "**ui_resolutions=hd**" only in manifest file. No need to add *'sd'* and *'fhd'*. Set the video node in your xml file as --

```
<Video id="videoPlayer"
    height="720"
    width="1280"        
    translation="[0,0]"/>
```

It will automatically adjust the screen, and video player resolution.

But some Roku devices have limitations. Some Devices doesn't support **4:3** ratio. For those devices you have to adjust the height and width accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, But It's Not Work. I also check width="1920", height="1080"

Comment: Check your device, which UI resolutions it supports. This should work if your device supports hd resolution. If your device supports hd UI resolution, then check your code properly. Problem may be somewhere else in your code.

Comment: I used Premiere+.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya I checked with same device. Its working fine for me. Check your tv resolution also.

Comment: I work with 720P on TV and Also Apply Logic for 720P in Roku and also apply Logic on to set translation, hight, width in brs File

Comment: Ok I play Hd Channel in Full Screen But Not Display FHD and SD to Full Screen.

Comment: Check by setting width and height  of video node to 0 once.

Comment: The output will be the same as previous.

Comment: I think FHD video convert By default to HD and display.

Comment: Can I change aspect ration on Roku?

Comment: I played two video 1 is an HD and another is an FHD. I successfully your way to play full screen with HD But FHD does not play with full screen. I set Its height width in FHD to screenplay include a black screen

Comment: Please check your tv resolution. I asked previously for same. Check whether it supports for fhd or not.

Comment: Sorry, I checked Its Supported and Edited my question.

Comment: Share complete code if you can. Will check and try to resolve the issue.

Comment: This is not sufficient to rectify the issue. If possible share complete code with your video file links.

Comment: Check whether these options are available with your device. If available try it once. Because in roku options very from model to model.

Comment: I only get 4 option 1.close captioning. 2.captioning track. 3.Audio Track. 4. Video mode

Comment: Ok. I will look into it tomorrow.

Comment: Now I play both HD(1280*720) and FHD(1920*1080) in Full Screen. But SD(720*480) is not playing Full Screen.I'm using Roku premiere+ Device Now.

Comment: good. for SD try to reduce the height and width by multiplying with 0.66666666666666. It should work.

Comment: Sorry, I can only display the video in full screen that has a 16:9 ratio. any other ratio Like 4:3 or any else not display in Full Screen. I changed the width and height in Roku. But It Set video player width and height. Not a Video Stream width and height. And Roku Not allows to Change ratio.

Comment: Thank you for Help, I used two ratios 16:9 and 4:3 But Roku Support only 16:9 ratio does not support 4:3 ratio. I change ratio in input then automatically get a full-screen output in Roku.

Comment: Yes, there are some limitations for playing contents on roku devices, and that very from device to device.